# Aegir hosting-queued service doesn't start

Tags: drush, aegir

I have installed [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/) on my Ubuntu 14.04 (inside a Docker container) following the [manual installation guide](http://aegir.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/manual/).

But when I execute `sudo /etc/init.d/hosting-queued start`, it replies me `Starting Aegir queue daemon... ok` but nothing happens, the daemon is not launched (I don't have it in the process list).

If I execute `sudo /etc/init.d/hosting-queued status`, it shows: `Aegir queue daemon is not running`.

I've checked inside that script and saw that it runs `su - aegir -- /usr/local/bin/drush --quiet @hostmaster hosting-queued`, so I tried to execute `drush @hostmaster hosting-queued` as `aegir` user and this gave me that:

```
The drush command 'hosting-queued' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions. [error]
```

And even if I run `drush cache-clear drush`, I still have this message...

Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an [issue on the project](https://www.drupal.org/node/2594721).

I've found a workaround which is not explained in the install documentation:

1. As `aegir` user, enable `hosting_queued` module

   ```
   drush @hostmaster pm-enable -y hosting_queued
   ```
2. As `aegir` user, launch the service manually:

   ```
   drush @hostmaster hosting-queued &
   ```

Comment: It would be great if you could submit a merge request to update the documentation to enable that module.  It would help others.  Thanks!